# In python 3.4.1, how can I assert an error in unittest like this?

Tags: python, unit-testing

For example, I define a function like

```
def f(n): return 1+'1'
```

and in the unittest, I define test_error:

```
assertRaises(TypeError,f(1))
```

But it just showed that this is a error. But when I define f with no argument like

```
def f(): return 1+'1'
```

and in unittest

```
assertRaises(TypeError,f)
```

it worked just fine. Why is that? How can I deal with function with arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called the first function *before* handing it to the `assertRaises()` method. You can give the method additional arguments that it'll then pass on to the function-under-test:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, f, 1)
```

The *better* option would be to use `self.assertRaises()` as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
    f(1)
```

You call the method 'normally' in that case, which reads a lot more natural.

See the [`TestCase.assertRaises()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

> Test that an exception is raised when *callable* is called with any positional or keyword arguments that are also passed to `assertRaises()`.

and

> If only the *exception* and possibly the *msg* arguments are given, return a context manager so that the code under test can be written inline rather than as a function:
>
> ```
> with self.assertRaises(SomeException):
>     do_something()
> ```

Comment: Martijn, you should write books, seriously :)

Comment: @alecxe: but then I wouldn't have time to answer questions here! Unless that was your *goal all along*, of course. :-P

Comment: Okay :( Reporting your "AFK" time intervals would also work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe: those fluctuate too much; but perhaps if you carefully observe my posting habits you could find some kind of pattern. If you do, could you let me know too?

Comment: Sure, but if I would do that I would not have time answering questions. See, the only solution here is to start writing books :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you should pass function arguments alongside with it's arguments:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, f, 1)
```

FYI, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises), this is the `assertRaises()` contract:

```
assertRaises(exception, callable, *args, **kwds)
```

where `callable` is your `f` function, `*args` and `**kwds` are positional and keyword arguments that you are passing in.